# Send Grid Status =Waiting for activation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I need to complete a task that needs to send an email confirmation after the admin submit from a button,but I do not understand where I am wrong and why email is not sending .

I verified the sender on send grid (it is a gmail account) and copied to appsettings json

```
 "SendGridKey": "SG.rrFAGo83SbqRvVZxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

my code looks like :

```
EmailSender.cs

public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
    {
        public EmailOptions Options { get; set; }
        public EmailSender(IOptions<EmailOptions> emailOptions)
        {
            Options = emailOptions.Value;
        }

        public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
        {
            return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, htmlMessage, email);
        }

        private Task Execute(string sendGridKey, string subject, string htmlMessage, string email)
        {
            var client = new SendGridClient(sendGridKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("admin@vmfhotel.com", "VMF Hotel"),
                Subject = subject,
                PlainTextContent = htmlMessage,
                HtmlContent = htmlMessage,
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

            try
            {
                return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return null;

        }

    }
```

in startup.cs I added :

```
//email service
            services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.Configure<EmailOptions>(Configuration);
```

My method in controller is async

```
public async Task <IActionResult> Change(int id)
        {
            var rsvItem = await _db.Reservation.FindAsync(id);

            rsvItem.Status = "Approved";

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            //email sender for confirmation email
            string message = $"Hi {rsvItem.ClientName}," +
                $"<p>Your reservation details at Hotel are:</p>" +
                $"<p>Name:{rsvItem.ClientName}</p>" +
                $"<p>Check in Date: {rsvItem.CheckInDate}</p>" +
                $"<p>Check out Date: {rsvItem.CheckOutDate}</p>" +
                $"<i>Bla bla bla </i>";

            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(rsvItem.ClientEmail, "Reservation Confirmed", message);
            
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

I do not have any errors ,but when I try to debugg it says :

```
+       SendGrid.BaseClient.SendEmailAsync returned Id = 453, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<SendGrid.Response>.AsyncStateMachineBox<SendGrid.BaseClient.<SendEmailAsync>d__22>
```

I read on a post on git I think that i need to make  private Task Execute an async

```
 private async Task<Response> Execute(string sendGridKey, string subject, string htmlMessage, string email)

 try
            {
                return await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
            }

I changed the                 From = new EmailAddress(" valid email@gmail.com", "VMF Hotel"),
```

with a valid gmail account

I checked the send grid and I have one request ,but nothing send

Where it is the problem?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, and thank you ahead of time!

Comment: I have this same issue you figure out what it was?

Comment: From the edit comment by the OP: `You cannot send emails with send grid to Yahoo mail`.

Comment: And please don't add extra noise like `[RESOLVED]` in the title. If you have solved it, write an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
return await Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, htmlMessage, email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Won't work because the host send grid is not allowing to send mail to the sender mail to send mail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is this meant as a comment on the previous answer? Or a new answer to the original question? If the latter, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other forums, this error is an internal response from the .NET framework, not a return from the SendGrid API, below the documentation link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=netcore-3.1

Here is the list of possible returns:

> Canceled  6    The task acknowledged cancellation by throwing an
> OperationCanceledException with its own CancellationToken while the
> token was in signaled state, or the task's CancellationToken was
> already signaled before the task started executing. For more
> information, see Task Cancellation.
>
> Created   0    The task has been initialized but has not yet been
> scheduled.
>
> Faulted   7    The task completed due to an unhandled exception.
>
> RanToCompletion   5    The task completed execution successfully.
>
> Running   3    The task is running but has not yet completed.
>
> WaitingForActivation  1    The task is waiting to be activated and
> scheduled internally by the .NET infrastructure.
>
> WaitingForChildrenToComplete  4    The task has finished executing and is
> implicitly waiting for attached child tasks to complete.
>
> WaitingToRun  2    The task has been scheduled for execution but has not
> yet begun executing.